# "View livewire not found": Unable to render a Livewire Full-Page Component in my developped package Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, view, package

I developped a package, and when it comes to render normal views, it works just fine, but now that I want to render Full Page Livewire components, I get a "view not found message" any idea why ?

For example for a show-tickets view:

web.php:

```
Route::get('tickets/list', ShowTickets::class);
```

ServiceProvider:

```
public function boot()
    {
        $this->loadMigrationsFrom(__DIR__ . "/database/migrations");
        $this->loadRoutesFrom(__DIR__ . "/routes/web.php");
        $this->loadViewsFrom(__DIR__ .'/resources/views', "Tickets");

        Livewire::component('show-tickets', ShowTickets::class);
    }
```

ShowTickets.php :

```
<?php

namespace UHGroup\Tickets\App\Livewire;

use Livewire\Component;
use UHGroup\Tickets\App\Models\Ticket;

class ShowTickets extends Component
{

    public function mount()
    {
        $this->ticket = Ticket::where("archived_at", !null);
    }

    public function render()
    {
        $tickets = Ticket::all();

        return view('Tickets::livewire.show-tickets', compact('tickets'));
    }
}
```

and I'm getting the following error :

> View [livewire.show-tickets] not found.

Although I do have a show-tickets.blade.php file in a livewire folder in my views folder....

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you've added the service provider correctly in `config/app.php`?